# Binary operations in a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it necessary that, for a subset $W$ to be a subspace of any given vector space $V(F)$, binary operations defined in $W$ has to be same as in $V(F)$?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$